# Odoo rpc query with join in C#

Tags: c#, odoo, rpc, pgadmin

I have this type of code to make a selection from `Odoo` `Rpc`:

```
XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
client.Url = LocalApplication.Url;
client.Path = "common";

// LOGIN BG
XmlRpcRequest requestLogin = new XmlRpcRequest("authenticate");
requestLogin.AddParams(LocalApplication.Db, LocalApplication.User, LocalApplication.Pass, XmlRpcParameter.EmptyStruct());

XmlRpcResponse responseLogin = client.Execute(requestLogin);

// READ
client.Path = "object";

// var x = client.Execute("select * from res_partner");
XmlRpcRequest requestSearch = new XmlRpcRequest("execute_kw");
requestSearch.AddParams(LocalApplication.Db, responseLogin.GetInt(),
                        LocalApplication.Pass, "res.partner", "search_read",
                        XmlRpcParameter.AsArray(
                           XmlRpcParameter.AsArray(
                              XmlRpcParameter.AsArray("is_agent", "=", "True".ToLower()))),
                        XmlRpcParameter.AsStruct(
                           XmlRpcParameter.AsMember("fields",
                              XmlRpcParameter.AsArray("name", "id", "phone", "email"))));

// SAVE
XmlRpcResponse responseSearch = client.Execute(requestSearch);

var agents = (responseSearch.GetObject() as List<object>);
Taswiq.Bussiness.Person p = new Person(LocalApplication.ConnectionString);

if (agents != null)
{
    foreach (var a in agents)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> agent = a as Dictionary<string, object>;
        p.Name = agent["name"].ToString() == "False" ? "ND" : agent["name"].ToString();
        p.Marca = Convert.ToInt32(agent["id"]);
        p.Type = 1;
        p.Phone = agent["phone"].ToString() == "False" ? "ND" : agent["phone"].ToString();
        p.Email = agent["email"].ToString() == "False" ? "ND" : agent["email"].ToString();

        MessageStruct result = p.Save();

        if (result.HasErrors)
        {
            return result.Message;
        }
    }

    return "Success";
}
```

All works fine, but now I need to make some join from this 2 tables like this:

```
Select * 
from product_template as d 
inner join product_product as r on r.product_tmpl_id = d.id;
```

I can't find anything but Python code.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. I do not know if is the best way but in my case it solved the problem.

I have made same list with every table that I need to go with join:

```
public List<object> lstStock = new List<object>();

 public void PopulateStockList()
    {
        XmlRpcClient stock = new XmlRpcClient();
        stock.Url = LocalApplication.Url;
        stock.Path = "common";

        //LOGIN BG
        XmlRpcRequest requestLogin = new XmlRpcRequest("authenticate");
        requestLogin.AddParams(LocalApplication.Db, LocalApplication.User, 
LocalApplication.Pass,
            XmlRpcParameter.EmptyStruct());

        XmlRpcResponse responseLogin = stock.Execute(requestLogin);

        //READ

        stock.Path = "object";

        XmlRpcRequest requestSearch = new XmlRpcRequest("execute_kw");
        requestSearch.AddParams(LocalApplication.Db, responseLogin.GetInt(),
            LocalApplication.Pass, "stock.quant", "search_read",
            XmlRpcParameter.AsArray(
                XmlRpcParameter.AsArray(
                    XmlRpcParameter.AsArray("id", ">", 0)
                )
            ),
            XmlRpcParameter.AsStruct(
                XmlRpcParameter.AsMember("fields",
                    XmlRpcParameter.AsArray("product_id", "quantity", "in_date", 
"owner_id"))
            )
        );
        XmlRpcResponse responseSearch = stock.Execute(requestSearch);
        lstStock = (responseSearch.GetObject() as List<object>);
    }
```

Same way for every table that i need to join with.
And in the end, inside the `foreach` i made that join that i need to populate my `sql` table

```
 public string DownloadRpcStock()
    {
        try
        {
            PopulateProdTemplate();
            PopulateStockList();
            PopulateProductList();

            Stock s = new Stock(LocalApplication.ConnectionString);

            foreach (var st in lstStock)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> stc = st as Dictionary<string, object>;
                var productId = stc["product_id"] as List<object>;
                if (productId != null)
                    s.IdProduct = Convert.ToInt32(productId[0]); //Din lista care vine pe product_id imi iau valoarea dorita
                s.IdStorage = 1;
                s.StockQuantity = Convert.ToDouble(stc["quantity"]);
                s.Rest = Convert.ToDouble(stc["quantity"]);

                var prod = lstProduct.FirstOrDefault(
                    k => Convert.ToInt32((k as Dictionary<string, object>)["id"]) == Convert.ToInt32((stc["product_id"] as List<object>)[0])) as Dictionary<string, object>;

                var prodTemplate =
                    lstProdTemplate.FirstOrDefault(
                        k => Convert.ToInt32((k as Dictionary<string, object>)["id"]) ==
                             Convert.ToInt32((prod["product_tmpl_id"] as List<object>)[0])) as Dictionary<string, object>;
                if (prodTemplate != null)
                    s.Price = Convert.ToDouble(prodTemplate["list_price"]);
                s.Batch = "NoBatch"; // Provizoriu
                s.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(stc["in_date"]);
                s.ExpireDate = Convert.ToDateTime(stc["in_date"]); // Provizoriu
                s.IdCustomerSuplier = Convert.ToInt32(stc["owner_id"]);
                s.Id = 0; //if (Id == 0) act = insert
                MessageStruct result = s.Save();
                if (result.HasErrors)
                {
                    return result.Message;
                }
            }

            return "Success";
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

I found many such questions on the internet without a solution.
I hope my solution will help someone else in the future.